# Apply plot properties to all MATLAB subplots simultaneously

Tags: matlab, plot, vectorization, subplot

I would like to create a figure, and once subplots have been created, I would like to apply properties to all of them simultaneously, without going through a for-loop. In fact, I would like to do all the following without having the need to go through a for-loop:

- Create all subplots without a for-loop. (For example, create a figure with 4x5 subplots, not using a for-loop).
- Apply the same background color to each subplot w/o a foor-loop.
- Apply the same axis command to all of them w/o a for-loop. (Like axis equal, axis tight, etc).

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The most convenient approach is to create an array of axes handles, and then to set properties:

```
for i=1:4,
   axesHandles(i) = subplot(2,2,i);
   plot(...)
end

%# set background to black for all handles in the array
%# note that this needs no loop
set(axesHandles,'color','k')
```

If you don't have the axes handles collected, you need to collect the array of handles first. For this, you can use the children properties of the figure window (`gcf` gets the handle of the currently active figure)

```
axesHandles = get(gcf,'children');
```

and if you have axes across several figures, you can use `findall` to collect everything:

```
axesHandles = findall(0,'type','axes');
```

From then on, it's again a single call to `set`, or to `axis`, for example

```
set(axesHandles,'color','k','lineWidth',2)
axis(axesHandles,'tight')
```

Comment: Jonas, thanks. So I take it there is no way to create the subplots without a loop though?

Comment: @Learnaholic: No, `axes` and `subplot` can only create one set of axes at a time. You can, if you want, hide the loop by using [`subaxis`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/3696-subaxis-subplot) from the File Exchange (this also conveniently lets you set spacing between axes).

Answer (score 2):

I can't understand why you think that `for` loop is evil, but anyhow ...

Here is an answer on part 2 and 3 of your question, assuming that the axes handles were saved in an array:

```
   a(1) = axes();
   a(2) = axes();
   arrayfun( @(x)(set(x,'Color','r')),a);
   arrayfun( @(x)(axis(x,'equal')),a);
```

`arrayfun` applies a function to each and one of the elements in `a`. Anonymous function in this case is only a shortcut for writing it in the following way:

```
   a(1) = axes();
   a(2) = axes();
   arrayfun( @SetRedColor ,a);
   arrayfun( @SetAxisEqual,a);

   function SetRedColor(x)
       set(x,'Color','r');
   end

   function SetAxisEqual(x)
       axis(x,'equal');
   end
```

Another possible way is to link the axes, and set only one property:

```
   linkprop(a,'Color');
   set(a(1),'Color','r'); %#Now a(2) color is also red
```

Comment: Andrey, its more curiosity about making the code more elegant. Plus this is going to be running inside a for loop anyway, so want to minimize total number of loops. Can you please explain the latter part of your program? How is this applied to all subplots? I understand the anonymous function aspect...

Comment: @Learnaholic, I explained better (I hope). By the way, if it were me designing the code I would do it more elegant by creating a function that does everything related to plots and call it "CreateGUI" or something like this, but that is a matter of personal preference.

Comment: thank you, I get everything except: 1) a(1) = axes() aspect of it. Where exactly are my subplot handles, is that a(1), etc? Why are you equating them to axes() like this? I dont get this. 2) I have a similar 'plotEverything' function, but I am updating plots on it at every iteration within another loop. (Optimization problem). Thanks.

Comment: @Learnaholic, yes, a(1) is the handle of the subplot. `subplot` is just a fancy call to `axes` with adjusted position. You can definitely change this line to a(1) = subplot(...)

Comment: There's no need to call arrayfun, by the way. `set` accepts arrays as input.

Comment: @Learnaholic, definetely check out Jonas answer as well, it is more elegant.